# AOSP build in emulator error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I built an android OS from source code, following https://source.android.com/source/building instructions.

aosp has a build-in emulator. however I keep getting this error when i ran it.

Some had similar problem with android-studio. I'm not using any IDE. It's quite confusing where all the config file located.

[image]

I'm new to AOSP. Trying to digging into android and make some contributions.

I built it on Ubuntu 16.04. The branch is -b android-6.0.1_r80

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue..??
I am facing the exact same issue with the Oreo 8.1 Build